# looping over dataframe rows for curl

Tags: python, string

I have a data frame that looks like

```
mid merchant_id class
0   5406382B06AC3CD335D8    "194174"    "Medium"
1   1B0D5A6ADD74F3EFBBB2    "5124178"   "Low"
```

I want to create curl command for each row like

```
'''curl --location --request POST 'https://api-msda.bharatpe.in/analysis/5406382B06AC3CD335D8' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"analysis": {"194174": "Medium"}}' '''
```

I have tried looping each row like

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
    cmd = "curl --location --request POST 'https://api-msda.bharatpe.in/analysis/{}'".format(row.mid) + " " +  "\
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'" + " " +  ''' \
--data-raw '{"analysis": {{}: "Medium"}}' '''.format(row.merchant_id)
    print(cmd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a separate json first and then add them into string formatting.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    data={
    "analysis":{
    row[1]["merchant_id"]:row[1]["class"]
    }
    }
    cmd = "curl --location --request POST 'https://api-msda.bharatpe.in/analysis/{}'".format(row[1]["mid"]) + " " +  "\
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json'" + " " +  ''' \
    --data-raw '{}' '''.format(json.dumps(data))
    print(cmd)
```

Comment: getting KeyError: 'class'

Comment: you do have a column name ```class``` right? what is the output of df.columns?

Comment: it had space in class